# Can't do Put requests on API hosted on my laptop and executed on another laptop

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch-api, put

I just couldn't find the answer to my problem online and I hope someone can help me.
I made an API with nodejs and express (with some help from YouTube and Google).
I was able to do some get and put requests on localhost.
I also was able to do a GET request on a different laptop,
but as soon as I tried the PUT request on a different laptop it doesn't even reach the server and it gives me a rejected promise.

- I tried to turn of my firewall just to be sure.
- I also tried postman, and postman was able to reach the API and do the PUT request.

Here is some code that might give some more context:
API (with an empty string sent it should give back a 418 code):

```
const { getAllSoftware, updateMachines } = require('./services/db');
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors'); // Import CORS middleware
const app = express();
const PORT = 98;

// CORS configuration
const corsOptions = {
    origin: ['http://192.168.1.99:94', 'http://localhost:94'], // Update with your client's domains
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions)); // Use CORS middleware

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`));

app.use(express.json());

app.put('/machines', async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    if (req.body = {} || !req.body) {
        res.status(418).send({message:'We need a json'})
        return
    }

    res.status(200).send({
        machine: `dit is je machine met je json ${req}`
    })

});
```

API CALL from different laptop (`localStorageData` is an empty JSON string `{}`)

```
fetch('http://localhost:98/machines', {
    method: 'PUT',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': '*/*'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(localStorageData)
    })
    .then(response => {
    // Handle the response here
    console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(error => {
    // Handle errors here
    console.error('Error:', error);
    });
}
```

If there is more information needed, please let me know :)
API's are a bit of new territory for me, and I am eager to learn how I can make this work correctly.

Comment: I just found out that i am trying to reach localhost on the laptop that is not hosting the api. Ive looked so long at this that i was not seeing the obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why I couldn't reach my host computers API was because i was trying to reach localhost:98. And as far as i know it isn't possible to reach localhost from a different laptop like this.

The solution was to set the url to my host computers ip adress.

Answer (score 0):

There are two main issues,
the first one is in the following part of the snippet

```
//...
if (req.body = {} || !req.body) {
    res.status(418).send({message:'We need a json'})
    return
}
//...
```

apparently what you're trying to do is to check weather the `req.body` object is empty or not, but by doing this `req.body = {}` you're assigning an empty object to `req.body`, this expression `req.body = {}` is a truthy expression, meaning that the code inside the `if` block will be executed anyways, you can instead either use `Object.keys(req.body).length` to check weather the object is empty or not, or check for a specific key as follows:

```
//...
const requestBody = req.body || {};
if ("data" in requestBody) {
    res.status(200).send({
        machine: `dit is je machine met je json ${req}`,
    });
    return;
}

    res.status(418).send({ message: "We need a json" });
//...
```

the client code

```
fetch('http://localhost:98/machines', {
    method: 'PUT',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': '*/*'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({data: "request data"})
    //...
```

The second problem is in `corsOptions`, try this:

```
const corsOptions = {
    origin: ["http://192.168.1.99:94", "http://127.0.0.1:94"],
};
```

Comment: Thats a realy good tip thanks!